# In a budget do you account for expenses of last month in current month?

Tags: accounting, budget

If I recieve june's paycheck by june 30th Ill be using that paycheck through out the month of july. In a budget then, should I add june income and july expenses in the same column?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get paid at the end of the month, then yes "June" income would be used for "July" expenses. But, if your income is regular, then it doesn't really matter. You just need to make sure that your total monthly expenses are less than your total monthly income. Whether you call it "June income" or "July income" is largely irrelevant.

If your income is *irregular*, then it's a bit trickier. You can't really think in terms of months but need to think in terms of "paychecks". That may mean June 30 through July 15th if you're paid semimonthly, or through July 30th if you're paid monthly, etc. Each paycheck is the starting point for the budget until the next paycheck. Obviously you can't always just blow it all if you aren't sure what the next paycheck will be like, so you need a larger buffer in an emergency fund.

Comment: It's kinda a matter of style like you say. But most people I know choose to use the pay cheque as the first amount and then count transactions up to (but not including) the next one as one accounting period, like you say. I guess uou could do it the other way round for the maths, ending with the pay cheque, it just seems a bit weird to us humans. :-D